# How to merge duplicates in 2D python arrays

Tags: python, arrays, merge, duplicates

I have a set of data similar to this:

```
#  Start_Time    End_Time      Call_Type  Info 
1  13:14:37.236  13:14:53.700  Ping1      RTT(Avr):160ms
2  13:14:58.955  13:15:29.984  Ping2      RTT(Avr):40ms
3  13:19:12.754  13:19:14.757  Ping3_1    RTT(Avr):620ms
3  13:19:12.754                Ping3_2    RTT(Avr):210ms
4  13:14:58.955  13:15:29.984  Ping4      RTT(Avr):360ms
5  13:19:12.754  13:19:14.757  Ping1      RTT(Avr):40ms
6  13:19:59.862  13:20:01.522  Ping2      RTT(Avr):163ms
...
```

When I parse through it, I need to merge the results of `Ping3_1` and `Ping3_2`, take the average of those two rows, and export that as one row, so the end of result would be like this:

```
#  Start_Time    End_Time      Call_Type  Info 
1  13:14:37.236  13:14:53.700  Ping1      RTT(Avr):160ms
2  13:14:58.955  13:15:29.984  Ping2      RTT(Avr):40ms
3  13:19:12.754  13:19:14.757  Ping3      RTT(Avr):415ms
4  13:14:58.955  13:15:29.984  Ping4      RTT(Avr):360ms
5  13:19:12.754  13:19:14.757  Ping1      RTT(Avr):40ms
6  13:19:59.862  13:20:01.522  Ping2      RTT(Avr):163ms
...
```

Currently, I am concatenating columns 0 and 1 to make a unique key, finding the duplication there, then doing the rest of the special treatment for those parallel pings. It is not elegant at all. Just wonder what is the better way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Are the duplicates always on adjacent rows?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your duplicates are adjacent (as they're shown on your question), [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.groupby#itertools.groupby) is the ideal way to identify them as duplicates (with a little help from [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html?highlight=operator.itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) to extract the "key" defining identity.  Assuming you have a list of objects (the pings) with attributes such as `.start` and `.end`:

```
import itertools
import operator

def merge(listofpings):
  k = operator.itemgetter('start', 'end')
  for i, grp in itertools.groupby(listofpings, key=k):
    lst = list(grp)
    if len(lst) > 2:
      item = mergepings(lst)
    else:
      item = lst[0]
    emitping(i, item)
```

assuming you already have functions `mergepings` to merge a list of > 1 "duplicate" pings, and `emitping` to emit a numbered ping (bare or merged).

If listofpings is not already properly sorted, just add `listofpings.sort(key=k)` just before the `for` loop (presumably emitting in sorted order is OK, right?).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the duplicates are adjacent you can use a generator like this. I guess you already have some code to average the pings

```
def average_pings(ping1, ping2):
    pass

def merge_pings(seq):
    prev_key=prev_key=None
    for item in seq:
        key = item.split()[:2]
        if key == prev_key:
            yield average_pings(prev_item, item)
        else:
            yield item
        prev_key=key
        prev_item=item
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure on how your data is structured, so I'll assume a list of dicts for duck typing purposes.

I'm also assuming the real primary key of your dataset is Start.

```
for i in range(len(dataset)-1):
  #Detect duplicates, assuming they are sorted properly
  if dataset[i]["Start"] == dataset[i+1]["Start"]:
    #Merge 'em
    dataset[i+1] = merge(dataset[i], dataset[i+1])

    #Deleting items from the array you are iterating over is a bad idea
    dataset[i] = None

dataset = [item for item in dataset if item != None] #so just delete them later
```

...where merge would be the function that actually does the merging.

Not elegant, C-ish, but probably better than what you are currently using.

They're not sorted?

```
dataset.sort( (lambda x,y: return cmp(x["Start"],y["Start"])) )
```

Now they should be.

Comment: never use cmp to sort. it is slower. use key: `dataset.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('Start'))`

Comment: Well I guess I won't have a choice with Py3k at any rate.